# History of asset in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, hyperledger-chaincode

I am using node.js to write chaincode and I want to get the history of drug in pharmaceutical supply chain. I deployed chaincode, invoked manufacture and buy contract which modifies the drug's current state from one owner to another owner. Infact, I just modified commercial paper chaincode for this. The change in owner is reflected in couchdb database. But when I try to get the history of drug by drug key it doesn't work as expected.

Code I used

```
const promiseOfIterator = this.ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(drugKey);
const results = [];
for await (const keyMod of promiseOfIterator) {
            
            const resp = {
                timestamp: keyMod.timestamp,
                txid: keyMod.tx_id
            }
            if (keyMod.is_delete) {
                resp.data = 'KEY DELETED';
            } else {
                resp.data = keyMod.value.toString('utf8');
            }
            results.push(resp);
        }
return results;
```

When I printed the results, it gives: `[]`
And when I do this: `Drug.fromBuffer(getDrugHistoryResponse);` and print it, it gives `Drug { class: 'org.medicochainnet.drug', key: ':', currentState: null }`

How to make this work? What am I doing wrong here? Please help me.

Comment: Can you please add a full chaincode reference here to identify drugKey reference.

Comment: It's same as commercial paper tutorial chaincode. I just want to know the history of paper in commercial paper.

Answer (score 1):

the function

```
ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(drugKey);
```

is an asynchronous function. So you need to add **await**

```
const promiseOfIterator = await this.ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(drugKey);
```

Then you can iterate over the result.

Comment: It then gives this error: ```TypeError: promiseOfIterator is not async iterable ```. And then I tried doing ```...for (const keyMod of promiseOfIterator) {...``` just by removing await, it then gave this error: ```TypeError: promiseOfIterator is not iterable```.

Comment: I have written a new answer to make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in a demo like that:

```
const promiseOfIterator = await this.ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(drugKey);
const results = [];
while(true){
 let res = await promiseOfIterator.next();
  //In the loop you have to check if the iterator has values or if its done 
  if(res.value){do your actions} 
  if(res.done){
   // close the iterator 
   await promiseOfIterator.close()
   // exit the loop
   return results
   }
}
```

Check the Mozilla Documentation for more information about Iterators in Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: res and results are same?

Comment: Hi, no I meant your result array. I have edited the answer.